# How do I determine function(s) that gives a bound Big-O and Big-Omega of a loop?

Tags: loops, time, complexity-theory

How do I go about determining functions, say g(n), that gives about O(g(n)) and Ω(g(n)) on the running time of a loop? I understand that O is the upper bound and Omega is the lower, and I think I can find O, but I don't know what to do differently to determine Omega. Take the loop(s):

```
for a=1..n
    for b=a+1..n
        Add entries L[a] to L[b]
        Store the result in R[a, b] 
    endfor
endfor
```

If I  determine a time complexity line by like, like n^2 + n^2 + n+ n (possibly correct?), that should give me a function, I think for Big-O, but I'm not exactly sure. So what is the difference between determining the two?

Answer (score 1):

If you determine true time complexity, for example `n^2 + n^2 + n+ n` then you can do "assymptotic magic" and you can say that `g(x) = n^2 + n^2 + n+ n = Theta(n^2)`. In that case `g(x) = Ω(n^2) = Theta(n^2) = O(n^2)`.

IF there is alghorithm, which works always the same for same size of input, then lower and upper bounds are equal, because it always run with same run time, therefore with the same complexity.

But if it does not, then you try to find "worst case" and "best case" input for the same size (which usually means abstract `n` instead of just input size of `47`) and thats O(g(n)) and Ω(g(n)).

---

For example imagine very simple alghoritm, which takes array of numbers as input and it wants to find, in which position is `1000`. The worst case is, that 1000 is not in input, so it does have to go all through, resulting in O(g(x)) = n. But if 1000 is first one, then it can find it in one step, resulting in Ω(g(n)) = 1.

---

In your case, you have to count how much times nested loop is executed.
First, it is from 2 to n, then 3 to n, then 4 to n, which is :

n-2

n-3

n-4

n-5

...

3

2

1

Which is sum of sequence (look here http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/algtrig/ATP2/ArithSeq.htm ) (n*(1 + n-2))/2 which is assymptoticaly `n^2`

Well and that n^2 steps executing these two lines

```
    Add entries L[a] to L[b]
    Store the result in R[a, b]
```

If they are done in constant time and it does not change on different input of same size, it is just `k * n^2` (for k being some constant) which is assymptoticaly still same as `n^2`, therefore in your case - lower and upper bounds are the same and you can say that `g(x) = k*(n*(1 + n-2))/2` and `O(g(n)) = n^2` and `Ω(g(n)) = n^2`